# Ajax get request not getting response after 5 calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I'm trying to get some information from the mongodb server to the frontend with ajax get request. Everything works fine except that if i try to call 5 times the javascript function, i dont get any response from my local server.

I tried to put some console.log() in order to debug in the nodejs function, it appears that the 6th time i call the function, the nodejs function doesn't even run.

javascript ajax front end code :

```
function addLike(music){

     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

     request.open('POST', '/AddLike', true);
     request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
     var myobj = {"music": music};
     request.send(JSON.stringify(myobj));

     setTimeout(function(){

        $.ajax({
          url: "/getAll",
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json', // added data type
          success: function(res) {
            // => the 6th time i launch addLike(music), the function doesn't go there
             update(res);
          }
    });

     }, 200);

}
```

nodejs function :

```
app.get("/getAll", function(req, res){

    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var dbo = db.db("SoundShare");

        var tab = dbo.collection('Musique');

        tab.find({}).toArray(function(err2, result) { 
            if (err2) throw err2;

            res.send(JSON.stringify(result));

            db.close();

        });
    });
});
```

As you can see on the image below, in the console of firefox the last get ajax request doesn't receive any response.

[image: Valid XHTML].
[image: Valid XHTML].

It seems like it is a server side problem but i don't understand how to fix it.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: 304 means it is cached, so set the caching headers.... Also add an error handler to the Ajax call and log what it says.

Comment: setTimeout after the post? Seems like a bad idea if you are expecting that call to actually complete.

Comment: yes I know i need to make the first post call asynchronous to call the get request once the post is ended

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are creating a new connection inside your /getAll function and the default poolsize is 5 as you can see in the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options).

You should be creating the connection when your node.js app starts up and use that connection throughout the application instead of creating a new connection on each request.

Comment: so how do i create a connection that can last all this time ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused because I have just started nodejs few weeks ago

Comment: maybe i should put an ajax listener outside the function ?

Comment: i am not familiar with the structure of your project but generally speaking you should create the connection at the same time that you initialize your app and express, etc, there are plenty of tutorials on how to do all that, like for example [this one](https://dev.to/aurelkurtula/building-a-restful-api-with-express-and-mongodb--3mmh)